# Newbie C++ Questions - Why doesn't this if statement execute?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have been trying to solve a problem on Codewars and ran into a problem with an if statement executing. If I test the following code, I get the error: "error: use of undeclared identifier 'out'", but if I use the conditional operator instead (see the commented line) everything works fine! I'm probably missing something obvious but could somebody point out why this is?

```
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
class Suite2
{
    public:
      static string game(unsigned long long n){
      
      ostringstream os1, os2;
      os1 << pow(n,2)/2;
      os2 << pow(n,2);
      
      if(n%2==0){
        std::string out = "[" + os1.str() + "]";
      }
      else{
        std::string out = "[" + os2.str() + ", " + "2]";
      }
      
      //return (n%2==0) ? "[" + os1.str() + "]" : "[" + os2.str() + ", " + "2]";
      return out;
    }
};
```

Comment: read about "scope".

Comment: Why don't you build up the string using just `os1`? There are plenty of common strings in your final output and the last line can be `return os1.str();`

Comment: There's `std::to_string` if you're using C++11. Perhaps a better replacement for your current use of stringstream.

Comment: You should use `n * n` instead of `pow()`.  The `pow` function is for floating point and you may get round-off errors when converting.  The multiplication is more efficient (doesn't involve a function calls).

Answer (score 3):

Your declarations (there are two of them) of the `out` variables are inside the scope of the `if` and `else` blocks; as such, they can't be accessed outside those scopes.

You need to define the variable outside those scopes and then assign values to them in the relevant block:

```cpp
class Suite2 {
public:
    static string game(unsigned long long n)
    {

        ostringstream os1, os2;
        os1 << pow(n, 2) / 2;
        os2 << pow(n, 2);

        std::string out; // Declare the "out" variable here...
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            out = "[" + os1.str() + "]"; // ... and assign it a value here...
        }
        else {
            out = "[" + os2.str() + ", " + "2]"; // ... or here.
        }

        return out;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The if statement executes alright, but you're introducing a local scope in which you  declare and initialize `out` so the outer scope doesn't have access to `out`.

Move it up a scope so it's level with the `return` then assign and it'll work:

```cpp
static std::string game(unsigned long long n) {
      
      ostringstream os1, os2;
      os1 << pow(n,2)/2;
      os2 << pow(n,2);
      
      std::string out = "";
      if(n % 2 == 0) {
        out = "[" + os1.str() + "]";
      }
      else {
        out = "[" + os2.str() + ", " + "2]";
      }
      return out;
    }
```

Side note: Stop `using namespace std;` and add `#include <string>`.